# Simple responsive HTML, CSS website table bug

Tags: html, css

I created a basic, simple HTML website for our clinics, however, the table content keep falling off the grid/margin (or whatever we call them). The view for ipad, web is alright but on phone is so weird.

Please help me.

I tried many way to have this sorted but it seemed so weird. I try to redo it but same thing keep happen.

```css
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style image */

.img-LHG {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

.img-LCG {
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

.img-me{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
}

/* Style the body */

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
  float: inherit;
}

h1{
  font-family: Arial, "Time new roman";
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial, "Time new roman";
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Arial, "Time new roman";
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-indent: 30px;
}

table{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

td{
padding: 1px;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: -10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Links Title */
.links {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-stretch: expanded;
}


/* Style the top navigation bar */

.wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color: #white;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {

}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: grey:
  text-align: center;
  padding: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 30px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Right-aligned link */
.navbar a.right {
  float: right;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


.side {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Main column */
.main {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fakeimg {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .wrapper{
    width: 600px;
  }
  .header{
    width: 500px;
  }
  .wrapper p {
    width: 500px;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .wrapper{
    width: 300px;
  }
  .header{
    width: 300px;
  }
  .wrapper p {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 200px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .wrapper{
    width: 100px;
  }
  .header{
    width: 100px;
  }
  .wrapper p {
    width: 100px;
  }
  .table{
    size: 20px;
    width: calc(100vh - 100%);
  }
  .table p{
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>London abc</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div> <a href="https://www.londonclinicgroup.com/index.html">
      <img class="img-LHG" src="img/LHG.jpg" alt="LHG"> </div>
       <h1>Welcome to London abc</h1>
       <p>abc</p>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
          <li><a href="contactus.html" class="right">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="side">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>About Us</h2>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <br>
      <h2>Our Clinics:</h2>
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th> </th>
          <th> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>HHC-we are a table content.</p></td>
          <th><img class="img-LCG" src="img/HHC.jpg" alt="LHG"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>HHC-we are a table content.</p></td>
          <th><img class="img-LCG" src="img/LHW.jpg" alt="LHG"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>HHC-we are a table content.</p></td>
          <th><img class="img-LCG" src="img/LHH.jpg" alt="LHG"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>HHC-we are a table content.</p></td>
          <th><img class="img-LCG" src="img/OPL.jpg" alt="LHG"></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
      <h2>Our Goal</h2>
      <p> Our clinicians are at the core of our business and we work tirelessly to forge a long term clinical environment.</p>
      <br>
  <div class="footer">
    <h3>Phone 020 xxx | abc</h3>
    <h3>©2020 Londonabc</h3>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: have you tried CSS-Grid instead of table? To me it also does not seem as tabular data in the first place.

Comment: Please also use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/). You have tons of markup errors (missing to close elements) which can also cause a variaty of different issues.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>London abc</title>
</head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  * {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Roboto", serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .header img {
    width: 60px;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .header>*,
  .wrapper>* {
    padding: 8px;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .nav-links-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 55px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  
  .content-wrapper>* {
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
  .table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .table-wrapper {
    margin: 15px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .img-LCG {
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .footer {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .footer>* {
    padding: 8px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div>
      <a href="https://www.londonclinicgroup.com/index.html">
        <img class="img-LHG" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="LHG"></a>
    </div>
    <h1>Welcome to London abc</h1>
    <p>ABC</p>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav-links-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html" class="right">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="side">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <h2>About Us</h2>
          <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-wrapper">
          <h2>Our Clinics:</h2>
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th> </th>
              <th> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>HHC-we are a table content.</p>
              </td>
              <th><img class="img-LCG" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="LHG"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>HHC-we are a table content.</p>
              </td>
              <th><img class="img-LCG" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="LHG"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>HHC-we are a table content.</p>
              </td>
              <th><img class="img-LCG" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="LHG"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>HHC-we are a table content.</p>
              </td>
              <th><img class="img-LCG" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="LHG"></th>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <h2>Our Goal</h2>
        <p> Our clinicians are at the core of our business and we work tirelessly to forge a long term clinical environment.
        </p>
        <br>
        <div class="footer">
          <h3>Phone 020 xxx | abc</h3>
          <h3>©2020 Londonabc</h3>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just check it... I have used some dummy images and also recreated CSS... Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you so much. That's so nice of you helping me.

Comment: Can you let me know why you using .footer>* and what does that mean?

Comment: Picking all the elements inside the footer... Can you understand @Tony Hoang